# Is there a python socket.io library that supports dynamic delivery?

Tags: python, socket.io

Normally in Node.js land, when you run a socket.io server, in order to easily ensure the client pulls the right socket.io library based on the server version, you'd simply load the library like so:

```
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

where that directory is served by the server-side socket.io library.

But all of the libraries I'm finding for socket.io support in python are requiring the user to load an external socket.io library from a CDN and manually ensure version compatibility. This seems like an objectively worse practice than the traditional Node.js way. Is there a python socket.io library that supports dynamic delivery?

Comment: If your concern is that on the client-side you have to load the library using an external CDN, all you need to do is serve the socket.io library statically from your server and then you will be able to load the library client-side in a similarly to how it's done in node.js, without the need of a CDN. At the end of the day, that's what's being done by socket.io with node.js.

Comment: @lnogueir my concern is that unlike Node.js which builds the correct client version for the server socket.io version its running all with a single module install, there seems to be no standalone python library which does so. The closest I've seen is a tutorial that demonstrates npm installing the library for Node and statically serving from the dist in python. So the result is you need to pip install python-socketio then npm install socket.io, and ensure both versions are in sync.

Comment: It's extra steps and extra concerns to keep track of. If I upgrade my python-socketio module, I need to remember to also go upgrade my npm socket.io module, or the CDN link in my client code.

Comment: Makes sense, it's a reasonable concern. I'm not aware of any other library that would provide something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Compatibility check is required because

> **The Socket.IO protocol has been through a number of revisions, and some of these introduced backward incompatible changes,which means that the client and the server must use compatible versions for everything to work.**

They have mentioned compatibility table [here](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#version-compatibility).